elasticsearch mongodb connector. documents stop being added after 60 seconds
I`m use elasticsearch  mongodb connector. Elasticsearch Enterprise
https://github.com/elastic/connectors
Documents stop being added to the search index 60 seconds after synchronization starts.
But the time counter does not stop at "Sync duration". It stops after ~16 minutes.
After the stop :
dial tcp 10.xx.xx.xx:9200: connect: connection timed out
tested on different versions of connectors :
8.14.0.0
8.15.2.0
tested on different versions of elasticsearch:
8.12.1
8.15.1

warning in logs :
[job_scheduling_service] can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
connector panel in kibana
connector panel
enter image description here
